# Primary Key in Create Table Function Has Multiple Errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What is wrong with creating a primary key integer column the following way:
'id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

This results in a red squiggly line underneath id, 11, and NOT NULL. The one under the id says "a symbol name was expected (near 'id')" and "at least one column definition was expected (near 'id')", the one under 11 says "unexpected beginning of statement (near 11)", and the one under NOT NULL says "unrecognized statement NOT NULL."

The entire statement reads something like

```
CREATE TABLE 'tablename' (
'id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
'orderid' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
'customerid' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
'email' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
'date' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost entirely meaningless (and frequently misleading), and probably best omitted; I think it's simply ignored in the newest versions of MySQL. And, as observed, (\`) is not the same as (')

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quote identifier names in mysql, you must use backticks, not apostrophes.